# RSA public/private keys in YAML

Tags: rsa, yaml, key

I need to store an RSA key pair in a YAML file, but a still limited understanding of yaml syntax and a lack of examples has me searching for an answer.

I'll just start working with what I've got, but I was wondering if someone could explain quickly and concisely how I could store something of this nature in yaml.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can store your keys as text ("ASCII-armored" / base 64 encoded). [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Whitespace_delimiters), the syntax for multiline strings in YAML is:

```
- title: An example multi-line string in YAML
  body : |
    This is a multi-line string.
    "special" metacharacters may
    appear here. The extent of this string is
    indicated by indentation.
```

Comment: how about a list? I.e. `script: - mkdir ~/.ssh/  - echo $SSH_KEY > ~/.ssh/id_rsa` ?

Comment: This worked well for me when supplying RSA Private Keys in Yaml to Python services for remote SSH work

Answer (score 22):

You can add the ssh key in your yaml file like below -

```yaml
---
ssh-key: |-
  -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
  b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABFwAAAAdzc2gtcn
  NhAAAAAwEAAQAAAQEAssBRe91wZ0TJBIWK2V1NH/ourcFPb0cA4ln32a3j5QITMS3zhs/o
  euh8jPJ9eca93B+mfep5ly/UjwmDctGbwX54sJngE4Vuv5FgqctR8oHTxV+V18UdolBSsy
  yiAVycGUexN2yz7P5JBzwfOG3WEwNe4dNVzmFj51nXAlaX+MB+wLfrZfU1vQpqmU8Esiu+
  Hdab948qhmGlMepBw+M4Z7wVfgfz855ywxgL3NrVk2WhXxE9ng/jTLjHKkxKE/3sM/81wt
  bvjejPvEMeFPD2XXBZSPi7TpgOiMBWDPXUwbrDYH6S6J2HAvYgwDm1pdQZGrOLrTBVJJE/
  DX1KpYZJzQAAA9DSZOo10mTqNQAAAAdzc2gtcnNhAAABAQCywFF73XBnRMkEhYrZXU0f+i
  6twU9vRwDiWffZrePlAhMxLfOGz+h66HyM8n15xr3cH6Z96nmXL9SPCYNy0ZvBfniwmeBP
  hW6/kWCpy1HygdPFX5XXxR2iUFKzLKIBXJwZR7E3bLPs/kkHPB84bdYTA17h01XOYWPnWd
  cCVpf4wH7At+tl9TW9CmqZTwSyK74d1pv3jyqGYaVN6kHD4zhnvBV+B/PznnLDGAvc2tWT
  ZaFfET2eD+NMuMcqTEoT/ewz/zXC1u+N6M+8Qx4U8PZdcFlI+LtOmA6IwFYM9dTBusNgfp
  LonYcC9iDAObWl1Bkas4itMFUkkT8NfUqlhknNAAAAAwEAAQAAAQBN1kUlROX/cgp+t5Ag
  2uoMtKrC6tymPir6ZebxmTEVtfOZhML4v2wiqT4jOiy9bHecdQPQ7NuJpEBREPl2dCP4/B
  OeA0OUHSx+qtWG2oySp0oKNndPf/xJg+SfNR5OrX8j2v4mfmVTG9+9EMcfkWSY3uzgNWC1
  /967DXn9AKwomx8yszA7YY0vKanLPx5C14WtzMPSbfwYZoKV4ddBHAF/7JHXAXxMisc9Ud
  kziaS8SV4YJt7gSYKKMvzOEj+uiyk9DKoYWf6t++SQ93CUnZKLfhwYTUx/rsYt6ubblQeP
  IHI/j8LKiVz6nvyDt2NXSJ2Z2j0s6roREYgnLaqbjlPZAAAAgQC6DgqTehb2XTrg69D8lt
  Lyo5sutB3bTIHyg6GBSBW2qYh3D2PQaWdrcYe7WYGtp6OGmTgGcXX0DBCCTtrwTdxsPVeL
  XhC/HBY271v9T18Ur4h310iJWVPJ8I7TgJuaSsfui/04NcqcW5XwFy6DHDQKxNwDhEscwg
  wIaUrd8UYfkAAAAIEA552RMzZ5OCAEryh1OXnV3EeqhumsCbET6dpDOpSQnHss7u3CZ8d6
  2LwHQJ/fjwDcrMYwEUwDkNoZjhEmj1e5LVTLjRS02VBgjg7RnphpuaphPZ+CDNlq3Om5C9
  xW96+4eC9/T7SRaspF3FxhgtPUMI1beu1QnpL0jduT/GQSqaMAAACBAMWR+CLktU6cTBH7
  RnfnB2K7E8slA8/hSGUZJ35JXJj5XujQgaf2d8hi4Lmt8smBojaERlCxxx3B9hWVYRkwCM
  C8YRNCLnBgR2CCp27D0wuadL9aFITlx91GPytF9BKxzy949VaF6SEw9M86oouj362u/BvP
  CO7Hnjlg77HRNFXPAAAAFWxrYW1pcmVkZHlAdm13YXJlLmNvbQECAwQF
  -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Please note that the SSH key is indented one level.

Answer (score 15):

As of 27-Oct-2016, this is the first result in Google when searching for "yaml rsa key", so I would like to add an answer on the specific syntax needed for RSA keys in Yaml.

If you include the key in a single line in the yaml file, there are no issues. If you want to split it in different lines for readability and you *cannot* accept newlines in the generated string, the only option seems to be double quotes with escape codes.

In my case, I needed a generated single-line, no-spaces string, since the key definition was being used by a templating engine to insert the key into a script variable. The following syntax will join each line with no spaces (please note the '\' on each line for removing the newlines):

```
    yourKey: "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\
      xxx...\
      yyy...\
      zzz...\
      -----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

    result: "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----xxx...yyy...zzz...-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

A very good reference on the formats for literals can be found here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/4228798

Comment: Also the first result at duckduckgo! :)
I would like to note that this does work, but in my case, I also needed to escape the `\` because it came from another environment variable. 
So I had a app with an environment variable with the key, that puts it into yaml, and uses it to start another pod in kubernetes

Answer (score 5):

It would be good practice to store your keys inside yaml file by creating pem files

```
 security:
   publickeypemfile: /config/env/xyz.pem
   keystorefile: /secret/pqr.jks
   testmode: true


xyz.pem: |-
  -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY——
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
……………………………………….
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Answer (score 1):

actual if copy rsa file ,it has \n\r invisible ,just use - in yaml file and watch out SSH key is indented one level.